# AI hardware architecture

Tags: integrated-circuit, computer-architecture, architecture, research

I am looking for more info on AI hardware architectures, but I am a bit confused. Here are my questions:

- Does it all come down to MACs(Multiply And Accumulate) units?
- Do MACs usually integrate into ALU like this:
  [image: MAC]

or the ALU in this case IS MAC like shown here

[image: ALU]

In case anyone is interested I got this from [MIT ISCA 2017](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/presentation/0342/8aef5a67184fa4329371569be4cd31b299e8.pdf) (page 124 and down)presentation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be mixing different presentations and different domains.

"MAC" in this context means Multiply-Accumulate, also known as Fused Multiply and Add (FMA). It's indeed the core operation for highly-connected neural networks including fully-connected networks and CNN's. The other main operation is the non-linear operation done on the result of all those MAC's. But since that's often a ReLu these days, that operation is practically free. (essentially one gate delay)

ALU (Arithmetic Logical Unit) is an outdated CPU concept. Modern CPU architectures don't have them anymore; the logical equivalent would be the FP Execution Units. They're definitely not connected to memory as in figure 1; they operate on registers. Memory wouldn't be able to keep up, eliminating the benefit of a dedicated MAC operation.

The second picture is a high-level overview of a new non-CPU architecture. This makes sense; you were discussing AI hardware and not general-purpose hardware such as CPU's.

Comment: I was indeed confused because the slide above mentioned ALU and i though that it is integrated. Thanks you for solving my confusion!

Comment: Why we don't have ALU in modern CPU architecture anymore?

Comment: We do. Especially in specialized processors like the stream processors in GPGPUs, there's specific units for integer operations.

Comment: @ptr_user7813604: The ALU concept dates back to the 1970's. It closely ties a single register to the transistors that perform the math operations. In fact, it's often named the "A" register, for instance in Intel designs. We now have a 64 bit RAX register, its lineage dates back to the A register in the 4004. However, the RAX register no longer is special; every x64 chip can perform math equally well on RBX, or R15 for that matter.

Comment: @MSalters: Thank you sir, thanks for your kindness. I will do some search to understand your words.

Answer (score 0):

Symbolic AI needs lots of pointer-chasing.

DeepLearning neural systems needs lots of multiply-accum math, **and** pointer chasing to access the various synapse strengths and their connections.

Comment: Actually, deep nets don't need pointer chasing. If you implemented it like that'you did it wrong. A good programmer will organize all connections in the order that they're needed for the calculations. That means the only pointer operation needed is a simple increment by a fixed size, typically 4 bytes. This sequential access is heavily optimized in hardware, to the point that many CPU's will auto-detect the pattern and prefetch the connection weights before they are needed.